# Make the code work on each element and according to own date

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make countdown using javascript and a table html element. The code works fine but the issue is i have two tables each table has own 'time' element and own date here in my code and i want to make a countdown according to his own  element value, this is the code:

```
            <article>
              <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <div class="post-meta">
                  <p class="post-date">
                    <time class="countdown" datetime="2024-11-30 08:50:00">January 21 at 01:00</time>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="mt-4">
                  <table style="width:100%; text-align: left;">
                    <tr>
                      <td class="days"></td>
                      <td class="hours"></td>
                      <td class="minutes"></td>
                    <td class="seconds"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th>DAYS</th>
                      <th>HOURS</th>
                      <th>MINS</th>
                     <th>SECS</th>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </div>
            </article>
          </div><!-- End post list item -->

          <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-6">
            <article>
              <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <div class="post-meta">
                  <p class="post-date">
                    <time datetime="2025-11-30 08:50:00">January 21 at 01:00</time>
                  </p>
                </div>
                
              </div>
              <div class="mt-4">
                  <table style="width:100%; text-align: left;">
                    <tr>
                      <td class="days"></td>
                      <td class="hours"></td>
                      <td class="minutes"></td>
                    <td class="seconds"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th>DAYS</th>
                      <th>HOURS</th>
                      <th>MINS</th>
                     <th>SECS</th>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </div>

            </article>
          </div><!-- End post list item -->
```

this is my javacript code that making a coundown:

````
<script>
/* Countdown for 'Upcoming Events'*/
// Set the date we're counting down to

var enddateTime = document.getElementsByTagName('time')[0].getAttribute('datetime');


var countDownDate = new Date(enddateTime).getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);


    // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
CountdownDays(days);
CountdownHours(hours);
CountdownMinutes(minutes);
CountdownSeconds(seconds);


  // If the count down is finished, write some text
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementsByClassName("countdown").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);

function CountdownDays(value)
{
    var countDownDays = document.getElementsByClassName("days");
      for(let i=0;i<countDownDays.length;i++){
        countDownDays[i].innerHTML = value;
  }
}

function CountdownHours(value) {

  var countDownHours = document.getElementsByClassName("hours");
      for(let i=0;i<countDownHours.length;i++){
        countDownHours[i].innerHTML = value;
  }
}

function CountdownMinutes(value) {
  var countDownMinutes = document.getElementsByClassName("minutes");
      for(let i=0;i<countDownMinutes.length;i++){
        countDownMinutes[i].innerHTML = value;
  }
}

function CountdownSeconds(value) {
  var countDownSeconds = document.getElementsByClassName("seconds");
      for(let i=0;i<countDownSeconds.length;i++){
        countDownSeconds[i].innerHTML = value;
  }

}
</script>```


So is it possible to get a countdown for each 'datetime' according to each own class date without repeating the function two times?
````

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I've edited my answer as per your requirement...kindly edit the dates to test

```js
const countdowns = document.querySelectorAll('.countdown');

countdowns.forEach(countdown => {
  const sibling = countdown.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.nextElementSibling
  const endDate = new Date(countdown.getAttribute('datetime'));
  const daysElement = sibling.querySelector('.days');
  const hoursElement = sibling.querySelector('.hours');
  const minutesElement = sibling.querySelector('.minutes');
  const secondsElement = sibling.querySelector('.seconds');
  
  
  setInterval(() => {
    const currentDate = new Date();
    const timeLeft = endDate - currentDate;
    if (timeLeft <= 0) {
        countdown.innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
        clearInterval();
    } else {
        const days = Math.floor(timeLeft / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        const hours = Math.floor((timeLeft % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        const minutes = Math.floor((timeLeft % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        const seconds = Math.floor((timeLeft % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
        daysElement.innerHTML = days;
        hoursElement.innerHTML = hours;
        minutesElement.innerHTML = minutes;
        secondsElement.innerHTML = seconds;
    }
  }, 1000);
  })
```

```html
  <article>
              <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <div class="post-meta">
                  <p class="post-date">
                    <time class="countdown" datetime="2023-01-16 12:38:00">January 21 at 01:00</time>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="mt-4">
                  <table style="width:100%; text-align: left;">
                    <tr>
                      <td class="days"></td>
                      <td class="hours"></td>
                      <td class="minutes"></td>
                    <td class="seconds"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th>DAYS</th>
                      <th>HOURS</th>
                      <th>MINS</th>
                     <th>SECS</th>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </div>
            </article>
         <!-- End post list item -->

          <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-6">
            <article>
              <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <div class="post-meta">
                  <p class="post-date">
                    <time class="countdown" datetime="2025-11-30 08:50:00">January 21 at 01:00</time>
                  </p>
                </div>
                
              </div>
              <div class="mt-4">
                  <table style="width:100%; text-align: left;">
                    <tr>
                      <td class="days"></td>
                      <td class="hours"></td>
                      <td class="minutes"></td>
                    <td class="seconds"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th>DAYS</th>
                      <th>HOURS</th>
                      <th>MINS</th>
                     <th>SECS</th>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </div>

            </article>
          </div>
```

Comment: It's working fine thanks, but what about if the date ended or get expired how to use this function here in jquery please:  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementsByClassName("countdown").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);

Comment: @HumamAl-Zaydi check the edits

Comment: @HumamAl-Zaydi cleared the errors...if you have any confusions let me know

Comment: last question please, and if i wanted to stop at 0 for each value?

Comment: stop at 0 for each value means?

Comment: if (timeLeft <= 0) {
      daysElement.innerHTML = "0";
      hoursElement.innerHTML = "0";
      minutesElement.innerHTML = "0";
      secondsElement.innerHTML = "0";
        clearInterval();
    } i get it))